# Get the row number inside an apply

Tags: r

Is there a way to get the row index of a dataframe inside an apply? Some sort of:

```
apply(df, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) { 
   numrow <- row(x)
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Typically you would do something like `lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) { x <- df[i, ]; ... })` ... maybe coercing with `as.matrix` first, which is what `apply` does.

Comment: what do you mean *get the row index*?

Comment: @Sotos The row num. In df[row, col], the 'row' value

Comment: Are you looking for `?row.names()`?

Comment: @MikaelJagan Ok. So the idea is: you can't get the row number (this info is lost inside apply), but you can build a SEQUENCE and use it as iterator. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are several ways. If it is possible that the data frame has zero rows then replace `1:nrow(df)` with `seq_len(nrow(df))` as in the comments.  BOD is built into R.  These print the row number or name and compute the indicated difference.

```
df <- BOD

spl <- split(df, 1:nrow(df))
sapply(names(spl), function(nm) diff(t(spl[[print(nm)]])))

sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) diff(t(df[print(i), ])))

apply(cbind(1:nrow(df), df), 1, function(x) {
  i <- x[1]
  print(i)
  x <- x[-1]
  diff(x)
})
```

Comment: Ok. So the idea is that you can't get the row number (this info is lost inside apply), but you can build a SEQUENCE and use it as iterator. Thanks!